# How do you mock isPlatform from @ionic/core

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ts-jest

Have a React Ionic app where I need to determine if the app is running on an iOS device.  I've done that by importing isPlatform.

```
import { isPlatform } from "@ionic/core";

const isIOS = isPlatform("ios");
```

I've tried the following and when isPlatform is called it still returns false.

```
        jest.mock("@ionic/core", () => ({
            isPlatform: () => { 
                return true;
            }
        }));
```

How do I mock isPlatform in my unit test using jest so it returns true?

Figured it out. I needed to mock ionic/core in order for it to work.

```
jest.mock("@ionic/core");
import * as Ionic from '@ionic/core';

(Ionic as any).isPlatform = jest.fn(() => true);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What framework are you using to test with. There is not enough here to answer the question.

Comment: Updated question to show using jest.

Comment: please attach the code of what you have tried so far.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Added code showing one thing I've tried.  I've tried a few others, don't remember exactly what they were at this point, but when isPlatform is called in the actual code it always returns false.

Comment: Finally got it to work.  Updated to show the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If component only uses isFlatform in @ionic/core you can mock one function isFlatform:

```
jest.mock("@ionic/core", () => ({
  isPlatform: () => true,
}));
```

but when component use another function and you only want to mock isFlatform you can use:

```
jest.mock("@ionic/core", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("@ionic/core"),
  isPlatform: () => true,
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the previous responses but using a slightly more flexible approach to be able to mock the result based on what we want to test in each scenario. **In our app we're using Angular but this approach should be working as well for React.**

The idea is to define a `mockIsPlatform()` function:

```
// Note: on our app, we're importing the `isPlatform` helper method 
// from `@ionic/angular` but that's not really important.

let mockIsPlatform: (key: string) => boolean;

jest.mock('@ionic/angular', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('@ionic/angular') as object),
  isPlatform: (key: string) => mockIsPlatform(key),
}));
```

Our service has some methods that use the `isPlatform()` method behind the scenes:

```
  public isIos(): boolean {
    return isPlatform('ios');
  }

  public isAndroid(): boolean {
    return isPlatform('android');
  }
```

So we can now test those methods like this:

```
test('detect platform', () => {
    // Simulate ios platform
    mockIsPlatform = (key) => key === 'ios';    
    expect(myServiceInstance.isIos()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(myServiceInstance.isAndroid()).toBeFalsy();

    // Simulate android platform
    mockIsPlatform = (key) => key === 'android';    
    expect(myServiceInstance.isIos()).toBeFalsy();
    expect(myServiceInstance.isAndroid()).toBeTruthy();

})
```